# Ng-repeats show in one controller but not the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I have 2 controllers loading in different places in my view. One works perfectly, but the other the ng-repeats are not showing up. They are also not showing up via ng-inspector. I have verified that the http data shows up in the inspector.

I am using the WordPress REST-API for both controllers.

Here is the main code:

```js
var homeApp = angular.module('homeCharacters', ['ngSanitize']);

homeApp.controller('mainMenu', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wp-json/menus/2").then(function(response) {
    $scope.menuData.data = response.data;
  });
});

homeApp.controller('characters', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.myData = {
    tab: 0
  }; //set default tab
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wp-json/posts?type=character").then(function(response) {
    $scope.myData.data = response.data;
  });
});
homeApp.filter('stripTags', function() {
  return function(text) {
    return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
  };
});
```

```html
mainMenu Controller (not working):

<nav ng-controller="mainMenu as menuData">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in menuData.data"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ x.items.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--end header nav-->


characters controller (working):

<section class="characters" ng-controller="characters as myData">
  <div class="char_copy">
    <h3>Meet the Characters</h3>
    <div class="char_inject" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-show="myData.tab === item.menu_order">
      <div class="copy_wrap">
        <h3>{{ item.acf.team }}:</h3>
        <h2>{{ item.acf.characters_name }} <span>[{{item.acf.real_name}}]</span></h2>
        <p class="hero_type">{{ item.acf.hero_type }}</p>
        <div class="description" ng-repeat="field in item.acf.character_description">
          <p>{{field.description_paragraph}}</p>
        </div>
        <a class="learn_more" href="{{ item.acf.character_page_link }}">Learn More <img src="./app/themes/big-blue/dist/images/big-white-arrow.png" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="image_wrap">
        <img src="{{ item.acf.homepage_full_image.url }}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="char_tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul ng-init="ch.tab = 0">
        <li class="tab" ng-repeat="item in myData.data" ng-class="{'active' : item.menu_order == myData.tab}">
          <a href ng-click="myData.tab = item.menu_order">
            <img src="{{ item.featured_image.source }}" />
            <div class="tab_title_wrap">
              <div class="h3_background">
                <h3>{{ item.acf.characters_name }}</h3>
              </div>
              <p>{{ item.acf.team }}</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <a class="more_characters" href="#">More Characters <img src="./app/themes/big-blue/dist/images/big-white-arrow.png" /></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also if needed here is the json for the controller that is not working:

```js
{
  ID: 2,
  name: "main",
  slug: "main",
  description: "",
  count: 6,
  items: [{
    ID: 43,
    order: 1,
    parent: 0,
    title: "The Resistants",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/the-resistants/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 41,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "the-resistants",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }, {
    ID: 46,
    order: 2,
    parent: 0,
    title: "Hyper-Action",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/hyper-action/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 44,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "hyper-action",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }, {
    ID: 38,
    order: 3,
    parent: 0,
    title: "Comics",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/comics/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 31,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "comics",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }, {
    ID: 40,
    order: 4,
    parent: 0,
    title: "News",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/news/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 33,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "news",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }, {
    ID: 36,
    order: 5,
    parent: 0,
    title: "About",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/about/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 27,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "about",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }, {
    ID: 49,
    order: 6,
    parent: 0,
    title: "Contact",
    url: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/contact/",
    attr: "",
    target: "",
    classes: "",
    xfn: "",
    description: "",
    object_id: 47,
    object: "page",
    object_slug: "contact",
    type: "post_type",
    type_label: "Page"
  }],
  meta: {
    links: {
      collection: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/menus/",
      self: "http://bigbluecomics.dev/wp-json/menus/2"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks so much all for all of the help as I am still learning angular!

Answer (score 2):

Your binding is incorrect on your `li` that holds the repeater.

Also, a little tip: try to stay away from using `ng-init` by putting that logic in your controller.

`<nav ng-controller="mainMenu as menuData">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in myMenu.data"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ x.items.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>`

Should be:

`<nav ng-controller="mainMenu as menuData">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in menuData.data"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ x.items.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>`

Comment: That was my fault. I corrected it, but still the ng-repeat is not even showing up....though the data itself is.

Comment: whats really interesting is that now when I inspect the DOM it DID repeat, but is just not actually printing the data in the <a> tag.

Comment: Looks like you want to repeat over the `items` object instead of its parent.

Comment: Thats correct I want to repeat over the items array and print the title of each object it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I belive I sorted it out thanks to the tip from @Pytth

```js
homeApp.controller('mainMenu', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wp-json/menus/2").then(function(response) {
    $scope.menuData.data = response.data.items;
  });
});
```

```html
<nav ng-controller="mainMenu as menuData">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in menuData.data"><a href="javascript:void(0)">{{ x.title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--end header nav-->
```

Thanks so much! Always great having another set of eyes!